# SocketAsyncEventArgs Send/Receive Order

Tags: c#, sockets, socketasynceventargs

I've been using SocketAsyncEventArgs for a project recently and I've come across issues where it appears that ReceiveAsync is occasionally getting data in a different order from what is being sent via SendAsync. Each block of data sent in the SendAsync method is maintained, but the blocks are not necessarily in the right order. Maybe I have an incorrect understanding of the SendAsync method, but I thought that especially using SocketType.Stream and ProtocolType.Tcp would ensure the order is maintained. I understand that the underlying process will inevitably break the message up and that ReceiveAsync will commonly read less than the buffer allocation. But I assumed that the send and receive streams would maintain order.

I carved out a test console program which shows the issue. It tries to run about 20 times using a different set of sockets and ports each time. On my laptop, it usually makes it through one time and then fails the second time; usually receiving a later block when it's expecting the second. From other testing, I know that expected block eventually does come, just out of sequence.

One caveat is that I was able to test it on a Windows 2008 remote server and had no issues. However, it has never come close to completing on my laptop. In fact, if I let the debug execution hang in the exception break for a while I've had it completely freeze my laptop more than once and had to do a hard reboot. This is my work laptop running on Windows 7, using VS2017. I'm not sure if it could be a factor, but it is running Symantec Endpoint Protection though I haven't found anything in the logs.

So my question is, do I have an incorrect view of how the SocketAsyncEventArgs operate? Or is my code a disaster (perhaps both)? Is it somehow unique to my laptop? (This last one makes me feel like I'm setting up for embarrassment like when you're new to programming and you think there must be something wrong with the compiler.)

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

static class DumTest
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 9177; i < 9199; i++)
        {
            RunDum(i);
            //Thread.Sleep(350);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("all done.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void RunDum(int port)
    {
        var dr = new DumReceiver(port);
        var ds = new DumSender(port);

        dr.Acception.Wait();

        ds.Connection.Wait();

        dr.Completion.Wait();

        ds.Completion.Wait();

        Console.WriteLine($"Completed {port}. " +
            $"sent: {ds.SegmentsSent} segments, received: {dr.SegmentsRead} segments");
    }
}

class DumReceiver
{
    private readonly SocketAsyncEventArgs eva = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<object> tcsAcc = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();

    private TaskCompletionSource<object> tcsRcv;
    private Socket socket;

    internal DumReceiver(int port)
    {
        this.eva.Completed += this.Received;

        var lstSock = new Socket(
            AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        var localIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList
            .First(i => i.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

        lstSock.Bind(new IPEndPoint(localIP, port));
        lstSock.Listen(1);

        var saea = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        saea.Completed += this.AcceptCompleted;
        lstSock.AcceptAsync(saea);
    }

    internal Task Acception => this.tcsAcc.Task;

    internal Task Completion { get; private set; }

    internal int SegmentsRead { get; private set; }

    private void AcceptCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
        {
            this.socket = e.AcceptSocket;
            e.Dispose();
            try
            {
                this.Completion = this.ReceiveLupeAsync();
            }
            finally
            {
                this.tcsAcc.SetResult(null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.tcsAcc.SetException(new SocketException((int)e.SocketError));
        }
    }

    private async Task ReceiveLupeAsync()
    {
        var buf = new byte[8196];
        byte bufSeg = 1;
        int pos = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            this.tcsRcv = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            this.eva.SetBuffer(buf, pos, 8196 - pos);
            if (this.socket.ReceiveAsync(this.eva))
            {
                await this.tcsRcv.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            if (this.eva.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
            {
                throw new SocketException((int)eva.SocketError);
            }

            if (this.eva.BytesTransferred == 0)
            {
                if (pos != 0)
                {
                    throw new EndOfStreamException();
                }

                break;
            }

            pos += this.eva.BytesTransferred;
            if (pos == 8196)
            {
                pos = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 8196; i++)
                {
                    if (buf[i] != bufSeg)
                    {
                        var msg = $"Expected {bufSeg} but read {buf[i]} ({i} of 8196). " +
                            $"Last read: {this.eva.BytesTransferred}.";
                        Console.WriteLine(msg);
                        throw new Exception(msg);
                    }
                }

                this.SegmentsRead++;
                bufSeg = (byte)(this.SegmentsRead + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void Received(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e) => this.tcsRcv.SetResult(null);
}

class DumSender
{
    private readonly SocketAsyncEventArgs eva = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    private readonly Socket socket = new Socket(
        AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    private readonly TaskCompletionSource<object> tcsCon = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
    private TaskCompletionSource<object> tcsSnd;

    internal DumSender(int port)
    {
        this.eva.Completed += this.Sent;

        var saea = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        var localIP = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList
            .First(i => i.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);

        saea.RemoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(localIP, port);
        saea.Completed += this.ConnectionCompleted;
        this.socket.ConnectAsync(saea);
    }

    internal Task Connection => this.tcsCon.Task;

    internal Task Completion { get; private set; }

    internal int SegmentsSent { get; private set; }

    private void ConnectionCompleted(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SocketError == SocketError.Success)
        {
            e.Dispose();

            try
            {
                this.Completion = this.SendLupeAsync();
            }
            finally
            {
                this.tcsCon.SetResult(null);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            this.tcsCon.SetException(new SocketException((int)e.SocketError));
        }
    }

    private async Task SendLupeAsync()
    {
        var buf = new byte[8196];
        byte bufSeg = 1;

        while (true)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 8196; i++)
            {
                buf[i] = bufSeg;
            }

            this.tcsSnd = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            this.eva.SetBuffer(buf, 0, 8196);
            if (this.socket.SendAsync(this.eva))
            {
                await this.tcsSnd.Task.ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            if (this.eva.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
            {
                throw new SocketException((int)this.eva.SocketError);
            }

            if (this.eva.BytesTransferred != 8196)
            {
                throw new SocketException();
            }

            if (++this.SegmentsSent == 299)
            {
                break;
            }

            bufSeg = (byte)(this.SegmentsSent + 1);
        }

        this.socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    }

    private void Sent(object s, SocketAsyncEventArgs e) => this.tcsSnd.SetResult(null);
}
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem (Windows 10 Pro) using the code you posted. The code looks okay to me. I wouldn't bother with the `XXXAsync()` methods in Socket unless I had a need for maximum scalability; the code is a lot easier to read and write using `NetworkStream` with the conventional `await`-friendly `XXXAsync()` methods. But I don't see any actual _bug_ in the code, and while with any of the async mechanisms available with sockets there is a potential buffer re-ordering issue, it only comes up when you have two or more read operations queued concurrently, which you don't.

Comment: FWIW, I increased your test code to run 20 iterations of the 22-port test, with 2990 segments instead of 299, and still could not get it to fail. Frankly, if you have any sort of AV software, that should always be the _first_ thing you disable if you start seeing unexpected behavior from I/O code. Bugs in that kind of software are all-too-common, and it's too easy to test that possibility for there to be any excuse to _not_ do so before asking some larger community for help.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to test it and apologize if it was just a waste of time. I naively thought that because the connection was made to and from the local host it would be out AV's scope. I had tried shutting it off and testing it with the same result though. This corporate setup doesn't make it terribly intuitive or easy to do so it was probably still running. I'll have more options for testing it tomorrow. Thanks for the sanity check.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Just to be clear: as long as you only perform one read operation at a time, you _will_ always get your data in the correct order. It's a fundamental guarantee of TCP (and in fact, the re-ordering issue I mentioned, it's not because the data winds up out of order...buffers are still filled in the order in which they were presented to the network layer, it's just that the threads processing the I/O completions can sometimes get to run out of order). So if you're actually seeing data out of order, _something_ is definitely getting in the way and breaking things.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in your code.

You must check the return of `Socket`'s `*Async` methods that use `SocketAsyncEventArgs`.  If they return `false`, them the `SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed` event won't be raised, you must handle the result synchronously.

Reference documentation: [SocketAsyncEventArgs Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketasynceventargs(v=vs.110).aspx).  Search for `willRaiseEvent`.

In `DumReceiver`'s constructor, you don't check `AcceptAsync`'s result and you don't handle the case when it completes synchronously.

In `DumSender`'s constructor, you don't check `ConnectAsync`'s result and you don't handle the case when it completes synchronously.

On top of this, the `SocketAsyncEventArgs.Completed` event may be raised in some other thread, most probably an I/O thread from the `ThreadPool`.

Each time you assign to `DumReceiver.tcsRcv` and `DumSender.tcsSnd` without proper synchronization, you can't be sure that `DumReceiver.Received` and `DumSender.Sent` are using the latest `TaskCompletionSource`.

Actually, you could get a `NullReferenceException` on the first iteration.

You lack synchronization in:

- `DumReceiver`, the fields `tcsRcv` and `socket` and the properties `Completion` and `SegmentsRead`
- `DumSender`, the field `tcsSnd` and the properties `Completion` and `SegmentsSent`

I suggest you consider using a single `SemaphoreSlim` instead of creating a new `TaskCompletionSource` on each time you invoke `ReceiveAsync` and `SendAsync`.  You'd initialize the semaphore to 0 in the constructor.  If the `*Async` operation is pending, you'd `await WaitAsync` on the semaphore, and the `Completed` event would `Release` the semaphore.

This should be enough to get rid of the race conditions in the `TaskCompletionSource` fields.  You'd still need proper synchronization on the other fields and properties.  For instance, there's no reason why `Completion` can't be created in the constructors, and `SegmentsRead` and `SegmentsSent` could be read-only and refer to a field which would be accessed internally with one or more of the `Interlocked` methods (e.g. `Interlocked.Increment` or `Interlocked.Add`).

Comment: The sample code given was just to show the issue that I was struggling with. If the code were used for anything beyond that I would of course take more care in how AcceptAsync and ConnectAsync were handled. The problem I described clearly had nothing to do with handling a successful listen/connect. Your synchronization assertion doesn't quite ring true because neither the sender or the receiver are running operations concurrently. I.e., a receive won't start until the previous one completes. I think Peter in the original comments did good job of helping me isolate the true problem.

Comment: So, what was the true problem?

Comment: Probably the antivirus software on my work laptop. Possibly something else but still specific to my machine. The important part was that the problem went away when tested on any other machine.